# xpath for HTMLagility pack on site with frames

Tags: html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to extract all the station names which are encased in the left frame from `http://www.raws.dri.edu/wraws/orF.html` using HTMLAgility pack.

My Xpath string is currently `//frame[@name='list']` at this point it returns the node but I can't seem to access any of it's child nodes. Ultimately I'm trying to return all the attributes that are in `frameset[1]/html/body/[@a]` which looks something like this :

```
<a onmouseover="popup('<font color=Black><strong> IDARNG1 RG2  Idaho (RAWS) </strong>    </font> ',615,307);update('IDARNG1 RG2  Idaho (RAWS)',615,307,'idIAN1','raw');return true;"  onmouseout="removeBox();removedot();" href="/cgi-bin/rawMAIN.pl?idIAN1">`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what the browser is currently doing:

- It opens `http://www.raws.dri.edu/wraws/orF.html`
- It parses the source code, and perform another request for every `<iframe>` that appears on it.

That means you need to open manually the url the `<iframe>` is pointing to, which can be found in the `src` attribute. Below is an example:

```
string src = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//frame[@name='list']").GetAttribute("src", "");
string url = "http://www.raws.dri.edu/wraws/" + src;
```

The URL you're looking for is:

```
http://www.raws.dri.edu/wraws/orlst.html
```

Go and open it manually and you will see only the left sidebar is loaded.

Next time make sure you use a HTTP Web Debugger like Firebug or Fiddler, to see what is happening behind the scenes.

Comment: is there a way I can parse orlst.html without having to go to that page?  What I mean is can I access the data in orlst.html from the original link of orF.html?

Comment: @user3421997 You can't. Both are different pages. You have to simulate what the browser does (in this case, open the iframes in different requests) unless you use WebBrowser, WaTiN, Selenium, etc. I don't see it too complicated: Why don't just perform another request for each of the iframes you want? You can use same cookies, etc.

Comment: I'll try your method, I was trying to reduce the number of request because there's going to be a lot of them to hit every station and retrieve the data I need.

Comment: @user3421997 Unfortunately you will have to make those requests. Just think that the browser makes much more (i.e. for loading CSS, pictures, etc :)

Comment: I was able to make the multiple request and finally got to the dates that I need at this page `http://www.raws.dri.edu/cgi-bin/rawNAME.pl?idIAN1`  I'm still a little confused as what's a node,an element or attribute using xpath.  what's the correct xpath string to access the year and month?  I currently have   //table/tbody/tr/td as my path.

Comment: @user3421997 If you ask another question about it, I'd be happy to help, but it isn't a good idea to do it through the comments. Also, if this answer solved your problem, mark it as accepted ;)